# How to get value from from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

First, please take a look on my code below.

My AsyncTask code:

```
public class loadNewMeeting extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int intCount = 0;
    JSONObject jnewmeeting;
    JSONArray attendants;

    public String doInBackground(String... args) {          
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attendant[userid]", Userid));

        jnewmeeting = jParser.makeHttpRequest(str_url_att, "POST", params);

        try {
            int success = jnewmeeting.getInt("msg");
            if (success == 1) {
                attendants = jnewmeeting.getJSONArray("attendant");
                for (int i = 0; i < attendants.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = attendants.getJSONObject(i);
                    int intRole = c.getInt("role");
                    if (intRole == 3 ){
                        intCount = intCount +1;
                    }                       
                }   
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.valueOf(intCount);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        countMeeting = String.valueOf(intCount);    
        SetCount(countMeeting);
            if (intMeetingNum < intCount)
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You get " + (intCount - intMeetingNum) + " new meeting(s)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intMeetingNum = intCount;
    }
}
```

I can't get `countMeeting` from outside AsyncTask. I tried to make Set and Get method but `countMeeting` still null. Looking for help.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, Where is `getCount()` and how do you access it in your code?

Comment: Are you calling that ASyncTask's [get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) method?

Comment: Is your `loadNewMeeting` class is within `Activity` class ? If yes then you can directly access any instance variable or method, if no then write a constructor of `loadNewMeeting` class and pass your `Activity's context` in this, then you can use any instance variable or method of your activity.

Comment: The AsyncTask and `countMeeting` is in a same activity. I want to get the value of `countMeeting` from outside of AsyncTask  but the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return countMeeting  from your "doInBackground" method?

As you don't use the "file_url" returned value, iin the "onPostExecute" method, just change the returned value of the "doInBackground" method, the signature of the "doInBackground" method, the signature of the "onPostxecute" and the third argument of the AsyncTask initialization.

Comment: How can I get return value in "onPostExecute"? I'm new in using AsyncTask.

Comment: The third argument in the initialization of the asynctask is the class you pass between the return value of the doInBacckground and the onPostExecute.